# Ufw don't working ERROR: not enough args

Tags: ufw, gufw

I have installed ufw and gufw in Ubuntu 18.04 with XFce4.12 environment. I was exploring its configurations, then I looked for some tutorials to configure it and when I run `sudo ufw` it returns this to me:

```
ERROR: not enough args
```

Then I run:

```
$ sudo ufw enable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/ufw", line 115, in <module>
    datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/frontend.py", line 165, in __init__
    datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend_iptables.py", line 51, in __init__
    rootdir=rootdir, datadir=datadir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend.py", line 54, in __init__
    self._get_defaults()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend.py", line 288, in _get_defaults
    for line in orig:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xac in position 4: invalid start byte
```

I can no longer start it, I have uninstalled and reinstalled it and it remains the same, any help please?

Comment: How do you install ufw ? I think it's came preinstalled (?) CMIIW

Comment: yes, it comes installed, I only installed gufw which is the graphical interface of ufw. but when it gave me that error I uninstalled them both and reinstalled them.

Comment: The `ufw`-command always requires arguments according to `man ufw`, so if you run `sudo ufw` you will always get `ERROR: not enough args`. But the error yout get with `sudo ufw enable` matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true, ufw always has to have a command below either enable, disable, status etc.
 Now I reply:

Previously I uninstalled them with:

$ sudo apt-get remove ufw gufw (which did not solve the issue)

But now I'm have solved it in the following way:

$ sudo apt-get purge ufw gufw

I have uninstalled them with the purge command, which according to I saw clean the configurations.

Then I reinstalled them:

$ sudo apt-get install ufw gufw

done !!! it's working again

Thanks a lot